# Как определить с какого IP-адреса был запущен скрипт?

Tags: php, битрикс

С помощью журнала событий было выяснено, что данный скрипт был запущен в браузере, 
есть только `GUEST_ID`. Можно ли определить, с какого IP-адреса был запущен скрипт?

Comment: В access_loge должен быть ip

Comment: старнно, что в журнале событий высечивается только один айпи, а именно айпи сайта, а не посетителей...

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Comment: @Дмитрий, надо бы узнать, кто раньше запустил скрипт....

Comment: @RabIn, а лог Apache, ничего не показал?

Comment: При соблюдении ряда условий можно узнать IP шлюза. Если пользователь сидит за натом - нет. Если на сервере стоит связка из реверс-прокси и не настроен проброс прокси - тоже не получите правильный ответ. Начните ликбез хотя бы отсюда: https://habr.com/post/177113/ Вопрос не на пять копеек, в общем. Для начала нужно описать, как у вас установлен битрикс, у вас например ответ для схемы nginx + apache будет одним, а для схемы nginx + php_fpm - совсем другим.

Comment: @Дмитрий, смотрю по адресу /var/log/httpd , там время запуска скрипта якобы стерто...
$
ip - - [20/Oct/2018:13:11:44 +0400] "\x16\x03\x01" 501 281 "-" "-"
ip - - [20/Oct/2018:13:30:56 +0400] "\x16\x03\x01" 501 281 "-" "-"
ip - - [20/Oct/2018:13:38:02 +0400] "\x16\x03\x01" 501 281 "-" "-"
и не прочитаешь этот лог...

Comment: @AK, nginx + apache